# pushSate on Chrome with back button is broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate

I am using

```
    $.ajax(href, {data: {_format: "html"}})
        .done(function (data) {
            $(".results").html(data);
            window.history.pushState("", "", href);
        });
```

This completes an AJAX request, pushes the `href` and replaces some page content.

If I then click a link on this page, inside the returned `data` which now sites inside of `$(".results")` that new page loads normally. Its just a `<a>` link to another page, it works fine.

When clicking the back button to return the last page I only see the contents of `data` - as a plain styled page.

So the forward motion works onto a new page, but clicking back just gives me the AJAX response, not the page as it was before with `data` inside of the whole page.

This doesn't happen on Firefox, but does on Chrome.

Comment: when using `history.pushState`, you need a corresponding `window.onpopstate` handler. What does that look like?

Comment: I do not have one. I added one, but it does not fire. Because its not popping a state? I am navigating 'forward' via a normal link, then back from the normal link. This doesn't popstate? It just goes back as normal. The issue is not navigating between states that were pushed. Its an issue when navigating back into a push state from a normal link. Make sense?

Comment: Ahh yes, that makes sense. It seems like you're running into a caching issue, and Chrome is making a request to get the page once you click Back, whereas Firefox isn't. You need to detect an AJAX request and return the full page (instead of partial HTML) if the request is NOT ajax.

Comment: When I click back, no AJAX is taking place

Comment: Right, which is the problem. It's not making an ajax request, it's making a regular request to the url that you passed to `pushState`

Comment: Fixed it by adding an AJAX only query param to the AJAX requests, but not to the pushState URL. Thanks!